# Spotify iOS SDK - "flip-flop" authentication not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify

I'm trying to do "Flip-Flop" authentication in my iOS app using the Spotify SDK [beta-14.](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/releases/tag/beta-14)

I'm trying to do this using SPTAUTH with the following code:

```
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[SPTAuth defaultInstance]loginURL]];
```

everytime that URL is opened, the app jumps to safari and NOT the Spotify iOS app.

What has been confusing is that, I have been seeing on Spotify developer forms that people have had the flip-flop authentication with the Spotify iOS app working, [link here](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/505). I for the life of me cannot get it to work.

Please shed some light here thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the necessary schemes in **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** and **URL types**? Also make sure you're handling the **openURL** call from Spotify app with: [handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL()](https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTAuth.html#//api/name/handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL:callback:). More info on how to implement is in [this](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/609) Spotify Github issue.